# read the whole file at once

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to write a function that gets a path and returns this file's content. No error handling needed. I've came up with the following

```
def read_all_1(path):
    f = open(path)
    s = f.read()
    f.close()
    return s

def read_all_2(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        return f.read()
```

My questions:

- which one is considered more pythonic?
- in the second function, will the file be closed automatically by the means of "with"?
- is there a better way, maybe some builtin function?

Comment: Most pythonic in this case is to not bother writing the function.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: I want this function to be used in expressions, like `do_something_with(read_all(path) + something_else)`

Comment: I think @StevenRumbalski meant the same as you want, for example using: `do_something_with(open('the_file.txt').read())` , which will be very "garbage collected".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are both quite pythonic.  To address your second question, in the second function, the file will indeed be closed automatically.  That is part of the protocol used with the `with` statement.  Ironically, the file is *not* guaranteed to be closed in your first example (more on why in a second).

Ultimately, I would choose to use the `with` statement, and here's why - according to [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/):

```
with EXPR as VAR:
    BLOCK
```

Is translated into:

```
mgr = (EXPR)
exit = type(mgr).__exit__  # Not calling it yet
value = type(mgr).__enter__(mgr)
exc = True
try:
    try:
        VAR = value  # Only if "as VAR" is present
        BLOCK
    except:
        # The exceptional case is handled here
        exc = False
        if not exit(mgr, *sys.exc_info()):
            raise
        # The exception is swallowed if exit() returns true
finally:
    # The normal and non-local-goto cases are handled here
    if exc:
        exit(mgr, None, None, None)
```

As you can see, you get a lot of protection in this case - your file is guaranteed to be closed no matter what happens in the intervening code.  This also really helps for readability; imagine if you had to put this huge block of code every time you wanted to open a file!

Answer (score 3):

I will say the second one , and yes the file will be closed, think of the `with` statement like this:

```
try:
   f = open(filepath)
   <code>
finally:
   f.close()
```

About your third question no there is no other way that don't involve opening the file.

---

A third way can be (without explicitly closing the file):

```
open(filepath).read()
```

The file will be closed when the file object will be garbage collected, but IMHO explicit is better than implicit.