# In Python, how can I open a file and read it on one line, and still be able to close the file afterwards?

Tags: python

While working through this exercise I ran into a problem.

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv
print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)

# we could do these two on one line too, how?
input = open(from_file)
indata = input.read()

print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata)
print "Does the output file exist? %r" % exists(to_file)
print "Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort."

raw_input()

output = open(to_file, 'w')
output.write(indata)
print "Alright, all done."
output.close()
input.close()
```

The line `# we could do these two on one line too, how?` is what’s confusing me. The only answer I could come up with was:

```
indata = open(from_file).read()
```

This performed the way I wanted to, but it requires me to remove:

```
input.close()
```

as the input variable no longer exists. How then, can I perform this close operation?

How would you solve this?

Comment: Thank you everyone. I feel better now. @Paul D. Waite Thank you for editing my question. It's much clearer now.

Comment: you’re welcome! It’s often easier for someone else to see what the crux of the question is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The preferred way to work with resources in python is to use [context managers](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-343-the-with-statement):

```
 with open(infile) as fp:
    indata = fp.read()
```

The `with` statement takes care of closing the resource and cleaning up.

You *could* write that on one line if you want:

```
 with open(infile) as fp: indata = fp.read()
```

however, this is considered bad style in python.

You can also open multiple files in a `with` block:

```
with open(input, 'r') as infile, open(output, 'w') as outfile:
    # use infile, outfile
```

Funny enough, I asked [exactly the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878844/read-the-whole-file-at-once) back when I started learning python.

Comment: Good style advise, but doesn't answer the question since it's not on one line.

Comment: @thg435, It's not standart way! Just file-object implements the Context Manager interface.

Comment: @astynax: yes, "preffered" sounds better.

Comment: @Junuxx The correct answer to this question is **don't do it on one line**. This is the best answer.

Comment: @Lattyware: Come on, this is clearly homework and while one should use `with`, it seems obvious that that's not the answer the teacher wants to hear in this particular situation.

Comment: @Junuxx I see no reason to believe it's homework, and if it is - it's stupid homework, teaching people to do things they should never do in the real world. SO is here to give a good resource, and that isn't achieved by telling people how to do something stupid.

Comment: @Lattyware: `While working through this exercise...` and `# we could do these two on one line too, how?`. Otherwise I agree, and I +1'd this answer.

Comment: @Junuxx That doesn't necessarily mean homework - this could be a tutorial he is following or whatever. Either way, the correct answer should always be to tell people how to do it the right way, especially if there is no good reason to do it the other way (or as in this case, the other way is strictly a bad idea).

Answer (score 2):

```
with open(from_file, 'r') as f:
  indata = f.read()

# outputs True
print f.closed
```

Answer (score 2):

You should think of this as an exercise to understand that `input` is just a name for what `open` returns rather than as advice that you *ought* to do it the shorter way.

As other answers mention, in this particular case the problem you've correctly identified isn't that much of an issue - your script closes fairly quickly, so any files you open will get closed fairly quickly. But that isn't always the case, and the usual way of guaranteeing that a file will close once you're done with it is to use a `with` statement - which you will find out about as you continue with Python.

Answer (score 0):

The file will be closed automatically and safely when your script completes.

Comment: Probably. But it's a really bad idea to get used to relying on this, because then you'll be useless for larger programs that have to open a large number of files over time. Refcounting *may* save you, but then you're tied to CPython and can't, for instance, make the program 3x as fast by running it on PyPy because PyPy has a better GC. Just get used to freeing resources as soon as reasonable. It's really not hard. -1

Comment: And even if refcounting saves you, you will get a `ResourceWarning` in Python 3.2 for each file that gets automatically closed.

Answer (score 0):

The following Python code will accomplish your goal.

```
from contextlib import nested

with nested(open('input.txt', 'r'), open('output.txt', 'w')) as inp, out:
    indata = inp.read()
    ...
    out.write(out_data)
```

Comment: `contextlib.nested` is pointless in more recent Python versions.

Comment: @delnan Worse than that `contextlib.nested()` should **never** be used for opening two files - if there is an error opening the second, the first will not be closed. This is a documented bug and it's one of the reasons it's deprecated in favour of the new `with` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a semi colon in between your existing code line i.e.

```
in_file = open(from_file); indata = in_file.read()
```

I think his is what you were after..

Answer (score 0):

```
in_file = open(from_file).read(); out_file = open(to_file,'w').write(in_file)
```

Comment: I decided so this task

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it lacks explanation. Please consider adding text to explain what it does, and why it answers the question posed.