# how do you open .txt file in python in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to open .txt file and am getting confused with which part goes where. I also want that when I open the text file in python, the spaces removed.And when answering could you make the file name 'clues'.

My first try is:

```
def clues():
    file = open("clues.txt", "r+")
    for line in file:
        string = ("clues.txt")
        print (string)
```

my second try is:

```
def clues():
f = open('clues.txt')
lines = [line.strip('\n') for line in open ('clues.txt')]
```

The thrid try is:

```
def clues():
    f = open("clues.txt", "r")
    print f.read()
    f.close()
```

Comment: I suspect what you're looking for is something along the lines of `print(x) for x in open("clues.txt")` (off the top of my head). It's not entirely clear what you're asking though; do you just want to open it or print it too?

Comment: possible duplicate of [read the whole file at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878844/read-the-whole-file-at-once)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python strip with \n](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9347419/1157100)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building upon @JonKiparsky It would be safer for you to use the python `with` statement:

```
with open("clues.txt") as f:
    f.read().replace(" ", "")
```

Comment: Yes, this is better - but the question asked for a single line.

Comment: @JonKiparsky True, but sometimes trade-offs must be made. I would rather the OP know the possibilities, and make the decision themselves.

Comment: @JonKiparsky the question also asked you to make the filename `clues` not `clues.txt` ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the whole file with the spaces removed, `f.read()` is on the right track—unlike your other attempts, that gives you the whole file as a single string, not one line at a time. But you still need to replace the spaces. Which you need to do explicitly. For example:

```
f.read().replace(' ', '')
```

Or, if you want to replace all whitespace, not just spaces:

```
''.join(f.read().split())
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
f = open("clues.txt")
```

will open the file - that is, it returns a filehandle that you can read from

This line:

```
open("clues.txt").read().replace(" ", "")
```

will open the file and return its contents, with all spaces removed.